# How to split an image file into chunks of n bytes to be sent to an api in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to upload an image to an API that requires it to be sent in chunks of n bytes at a time (The chunk size is dynamic and I get that earlier). The parameters for the request are the chunk index and the image payload. So if I have the file, how would I go about splitting it into n-byte chunks to send in an axios request? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what API is this?  Seems really weird.

Comment: @Brad a niche platform I use for work, is kinda weird

Comment: Lots of options.  You can use `fs.createReadStream()` and pass the `start` and `end` options to it for where you want it to start and stop in the file (thus reading a chunk).  Or, you can use `fs.open()` followed by `fs.read()` and specify a chunk of the file to read in the `fs.read()` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-file) npm package to do that

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options to get a chunk of a file.  Here are some of those options:

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {start: firstByte, end: lastByte});
```

Then, you can pipe that stream to a response or attach your own `data` listener and as the bytes from the stream come in, you do something with them.  The `start` and `end` options will automatically limit the stream to that particular chunk of the file.

---

You could also open the file, then read a specific chunk with `fs.read()` where you pass the `position` and `length` arguments.